# Считывание алгебраического выражения из поля для ввода и его дальнейшее вычисление

Tags: delphi, lazarus

Есть поле ввода, в него записывается алгебраическое выражение, например: (((3+5)*sqrt(9))/(5^2)) . Необходимо считать выражение из поля и вычислить его после. Мой ход мыслей таков: присваиваем какой-нибудь переменной значение из Edit'а, посимвольно считываем из неё с помощью каких-нибудь if-else, а дальше что? Если бы выражение было простым, вроде 2+2, то тут всё понятно, а как быть с такими сложными выражениями? Программа должна работать на Винде.

Comment: Используйте алгоритм обратной польской записи.

Comment: Помимо написания своего велосипеда, есть как минимум 2 варианта: воспользоваться интерпретатором выражений (например, в JEDI VCL есть JVInterpreter) или скриптовым движком (например PascalScript). Не уверен, что они работают под Lazarus, но думаю, отыскать похожее не составит большого труда.